# Take the middle of the top border away

Tags: html, css

I try to get the middle of the top stripe of the border away but not the whole top, how can I do this?
I am doing Html. I tried a lot but without success I hope anyone can help me.

Comment: Could you please give me your code?

Comment: Can you share your design? How it should look like.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood you question correctly, something basic like this would hide the middle of the top border:

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 10px solid #000;
}

.box .mask {
  border-top: 10px solid #fff;
  width: 100px;  
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: 100px;  
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="mask"></div>
</div>
```